# Using Moq to Stub an interface method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, stub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mock a method that returns an int with MOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962636/how-to-mock-a-method-that-returns-an-int-with-moq)

Here's my interface:

```
public interface ICalenderService
    {
        DateTime Adjust(DateTime dateToAdjust, BusinessDayConvention convention, List<HolidayCity> holidayCities);
    }
```

I've done some research and it seems you can mock this real easily, but I want to stub this out using Moq so that I can pass the stub into my other class constuctors and have the stub return whatever `DateTime` I want for its `Adjust` method.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Edit: I know I can create my own stub in my project, but I'd like to write less code, and I think Moq can let me do that, I  just don't know what the syntax looks like.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. The example in the other question had a parameterless method, but the method on this interface exposes three parameters that'd need to be mocked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set up the stub like this:

```
var calendarServiceStub = new Mock<ICalenderService>();

calendarServiceStub
    .Setup(c => c.Adjust(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<BusinessDayConvention>(), It.IsAny<List<HolidayCity>>()))
    .Returns(theDateTimeResultYouWant);
```

Pass `calendarServiceStub.Object` to the other class's constructor.