# What Is Object Under Test vs. Collaborator here?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm trying to figure out how to do my first Mock with Moq.  I'm new to mocking as well.

Lets say I have the following TDD test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PreAuthorize_WithEmptyRequest_ReturnsNonNullResponse()
{
    // Arrange
    var preAuthorizeRequest = new PreAuthorizeRequest();

    // Act
    var authorizeResponse = _dataProcessor.SendRequest(preAuthorizeRequest);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(authorizeResponse);
}
```

The scenario for that test above is that if we send in an object instance that has no state, we should still get back a response object (it shouldn't blow up).  So I guess in Mock and Stub terms I guess I want to test the behavior of the dataProcessor's SendRequest method in that it'll send back an instance of PreAuthorizeResponse....right?

Now here's the info on what these types are:

```
    public interface IPaymentRequest
    {
        string SecurityToken { get; set; }
        int RetailID { get; set; }
        int ProcessorId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PreAuthorizeRequest : IPaymentRequest
    {
        public string SecurityToken { get; set; }
        public int RetailID { get; set; }
        public int ProcessorId { get; set; }
        public PreAuthorizeTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
    }

       public IPaymentResponse SendRequest(IPaymentRequest request)
        {
            ITransaction transaction = PaymentUtilities.GetPaymentRequestTransactionType(request);
            IPaymentResponse response = PaymentUtilities.GetPaymentResponseType(request);
            var transactionType = PaymentUtilities.GetPaymentRequestTransactionTypeEnum(request);
            var requestValidator = new PaymentRequestValidator();

            requestValidator.ValidateRequest(request);

            var requestIsValid = requestValidator.RequestIsValid;

            if (!requestIsValid)
            {
                response = PaymentUtilities.BuildPaymentResponse(request, requestValidator, transaction, transactionType);
                return response;
            }
IAutoPaymentProcessor autoPaymentProcessor = CreateAutoPaymentProcessor(request);
            var configValidator = new ConfigurationValidator(autoPaymentProcessor);

            configValidator.ValidateConfigurationSettings();
            bool settingsAreValid = configValidator.ConfigIsValid;

            if (!settingsAreValid)
            {
                response = PaymentUtilities.BuildPaymentResponse(request, requestValidator, transaction, transactionType);
                return response;
            }

            response = SetConfigSettings(request, response);

            Document dataResponseDoc = SendRequest(request, response);
            response.PaymentProcessorId = (int)Enums.PaymentProcessorType.Data;
            response.ProviderAuthCode = dataResponseDoc != null ? dataResponseDoc.get("Response.authcode") : string.Empty;
            response.ProviderReference = dataResponseDoc != null ? dataResponseDoc.get("Response.data_reference") : string.Empty;

            return response;
        }
```

So I don't see the need for a mock, in other words a verify call on the mock right?  I think I just need a stub and to test whether I get an instance of PreAuthorizeResponse back.  So I guess that's a stub with Moq right?

Well then how would I do this with Moq if I'm right about me only needing to work with a stub here?

I tried this but I feel this is wrong since I feel the SUT is my data processor which I believe you should not mock the object in test:

```
    [TestMethod]
public void PreAuthorize_WithEmptyRequest_ReturnsNonNullResponse()
{
    // Arrange - setup data
    var dataProcessorStub = new Mock<IPaymentProcessor>();
    var preAuthorizeRequest = new PreAuthorizeRequest();

    // Act
    //setup - expectations
    dataProcessorStub.Setup(p => p.SendRequest(It.IsAny<PreAuthorizeRequest>())).Returns(It.IsAny<PreAuthorizeResponse>());

    // excercise
    var preAuthorizeResponse = dataProcessorStub.Object.SendRequest(preAuthorizeRequest);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(preAuthorizeResponse, typeof(PreAuthorizeResponse));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't really want to be mocking the object you are trying to test. You should mock the dependencies of that object (e.g. the database object).

The `dataProcessor` is the Object under Test (also known as System under Test), and everything else are collaborators (dependencies of the SUT).

You are going to find it difficult to test this properly though, due to the number of hard dependencies that you have within the `SendRequest` method.

At the very least, you want to mock the `PaymentRequestValidator` so that when you send in a specific type of request, you can have the mock setup to say that it is not valid, and then handle that in the code, which in turn will cause the `SendRequest` method to return a response.

To achieve that though, you will need to refactor your code in order to pass a mocked instance of the request validator in. Also, probably quite a few of the other objects as well.

For example, you'll more than likely need to mock the `PaymentUtilities` object so that you can have the methods you use return Mock objects, which are themselves setup to return specific things for this test. Similarly the `ConfigurationValidator` - will it return a valid configuration when it is called from the test (probably a different test), or do you need to mock that as well?

This is heading well into the realms of *dependency injection* and *inversion of control*. I won't insult you are by providing links, but those subjects are well covered in literature both in print and on the web.

Comment: and so how would I mock PaymentRequestValidator, when that validator is something being used IN my SendRequest method?

Comment: Yes, your ```SendRequest``` method is probably doing too much. You could either modify the ```SendRequest``` method to accept an ```IPaymentRequestValidator```, or modify the data processor class itself to accept a payment request validator object as either a constructor parameter, or a property.

Comment: this crap is not easy is it :)

Comment: Plus that SendRequest is using a Data Layer class which I suppose should be mocked as well?  It's another dependency

Comment: then what do you think about this post, they say to mock in order to stub http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505704/using-moq-to-stub-an-interface-method

Comment: Yep, that question is about mocking interfaces. So if your data process object was something like ```public class DataProcessor { public DataProcessor(IPaymentRequestValidator validator){} .... }```, then you would create the mock validator in your test as in that question, and then do ```var dataprocessor = new DataProcessor(mockPaymentRequestValidator.Object)```

Comment: but if the PaymentUtilities is not hitting any external dependencies like in memory, database, file system I should not have to mock it right?

Comment: Yes, assuming that ```PaymentUtilities``` behaves correctly when in called in the context of a test, you won't have to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems like you don't need to do any mocking if you are trying to test the `SendRequest` method. You need to mock the dependencies of what you are trying to test, not the object under test itself. So if your `PaymentProcessor` had any external dependencies required for the test you'd need to mock those.

The `SendRequest` method does take an interface which you can mock, but it's easier to just pass in a newly created `PreAuthorizeRequest`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void PreAuthorize_WithEmptyRequest_ReturnsNonNullResponse()
{
    // Arrange
    var preAuthorizeRequest = new PreAuthorizeRequest();

    // Act
    var authorizeResponse = _dataProcessor.SendRequest(preAuthorizeRequest);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(authorizeResponse);
}
```

Alternatively you can mock the request:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void PreAuthorize_WithEmptyRequest_ReturnsNonNullResponse()
 {
     // Arrange
     var request = new Mock<IPaymentRequest>();

     // Act
     var authorizeResponse = _dataProcessor.SendRequest(request);

     // Assert
     Assert.IsNotNull(authorizeResponse);
 }
```

Comment: so you're saying in this case we do not want to mock the processor class because it's the object under test (and its method is under test) so the only thing we can mock here is the IPaymentRequest right?

Comment: Yea but then I also have the issue the other guys mentioned is my SendRequest method is doing too much and has other dependencies that I cannot mock, so I'm gonna have to refactor that method or somehow inject the stuff like the verification class, and the data layer class into it via interface or abstract class or something I guess

Comment: isn't the whole point here to not have any dependencies?  So does that mean I should be mocking the stuff that's coupled inside currently in the SendRequest, that should be decoupled so I can mock them (validation, database types, etc.)?

Comment: I can't send in a new Mock<IPaymentRequest>(); to SendRequest, it has a type mismatch error saying it can't convert new Mock<IPaymentRequest> to IPaymentRequest

Comment: nevermind I think it's new var preAuthorizeRequestStub = new Mock<IPaymentRequest>(); then preAuthorizeRequestStub.Object